# Is open-to-all CORS safe for non-cookie-based authentication schemes (e.g. OAuth)

Tags: access-control

I'm building an API with both protected and public endpoints, and I'm protecting it with OAuth 2's various flows. I want this API to be open to the world - the main consumer website won't even be on the same origin as the API server. So I'm planning to implement CORS.

Many texts warn about malicious third parties "sending requests as *the user*", but I'm not sure what they mean by that. I *assume* this is similar to how CSRF works - as in, the requests get sent across with the user's cookies.

If this is the case, since my OAuth 2 authentication scheme uses tokens passed around via HTTP header or a GET parameter, wouldn't this not be an issue at all? My service doesn't even touch cookies at all.

Any third parties attempting to do a protected operation on behalf of the user wouldn't have access to a valid token (which is stored on local storage or in-memory). *Or* unless the user explicitly invokes an OAuth 2 flow, gives the third party a valid token, and it uses that (working as intended) - *or* it's not an operation that requires the user to be authenticated, which would work (also working as intended).

Of course, as we all know, when I assume I make an ass out of *oh god we're compromised there are kittens everywhere*, so I could very well be wrong and there's bigger security gap than just cookies. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> "sending requests as the user", but I'm not sure what they mean by that. I assume this is similar to how CSRF works

Exactly.

---

> as in, the requests get sent across with the user's cookies.

CSRF doesn't necessarily require cookies.  It's just easier with cookies because they're automatically attached to any request to a particular origin.

If the authorizing credentials are guessable or stealable then a third-party iframe can forge a request with them.  CORS just makes it easier to forge a request with headers that aren't usually part of a browser initiated GET or POST.

If you're doing authorization via secrets in the URL, I'd make sure your CORS service includes the [appropriate headers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18516720/20394) so that you're not vulnerable to [history sniffing](http://lcamtuf.coredump.cx/cachetime/) and similar side channel attacks.  OAuth's embedded parameters should have enough entropy that they're safe against sniffing, but there's always referrer leakage from your side to take care of, so those headers are a good idea.

---

> Any third parties attempting to do a protected operation on behalf of the user wouldn't have access to a valid token (which is stored on local storage or in-memory).

It looks like you've got a handle on the major attack vectors.

If it's stored in local-storage, then an XSS on any page with access to that local-storage could leak the token.

If you can't keep the token in an origin that doesn't include HTML with third-party content, then there may be tricks you can do with `document.domain` to limit the window of exposure to injected scripts on any page that's in the same origin as the token.

1. load JS that fetches and sequesters the token using closure integrity to provide an API to other JS in the page without exposing the token value itself.
2. change the page origin so that you no longer have access to local-storage
3. proceed to run the rest of the page script which might have injected content

Also, CSP might provide defense-in-depth down the road.

Comment: I need to store the token somewhere locally to accommodate for "remember me" functionality; would there be a more suitable place to put it? I was working under the idea that XSS would compromise us in bigger ways, but it makes sense to not add an additional hole.

Comment: Forgot to add: Thing is, token storage is a decision on the middleman's side; while we can always encourage API consumers to store safer, we can't enforce it. I'm not sure if there's a better-practice for this.

Comment: @bananapeel, if token storage is done by the middleman, is it in an origin that is accessible from an origin that you serve complex HTML on, or does the middleman gate access to it somehow?

Comment: Sorry, I don't follow. I'm storing tokens within the API server and handing them out to the API consumers (acting as middlemen). These consumers are free to decide if they want to offer HTML or whatever service they want.